# Using translate3d in chrome creates blank space at bottom of page

Tags: css, google-chrome, transform, translate3d

I'm having a problem animating a div using the `translate3d` CSS property.
The `.box` div has to slide up in the page and the `.container` div has to move up of some pixel.

The animation works great, unless you scroll the page all the way down before triggering it. If you scroll the page down and start the animation a blank space pops up from nowhere and there's no way I can figure out what is that.

[Here's the CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgzLrK)

```js
$("input.toggle").click(function () {
    $('.container').toggleClass('move');
$('.box').toggleClass('move');
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 800px;
  /* this is not necessary, it's just a way to avoid putting a lot more text since the issue happens when you scroll all the way down before clicking on the toggle*/
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

input.toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 700px;
  left: 50%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0.4, 1);
  -moz-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0.4, 1);
  transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0.4, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.container p {
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}
.container.move {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0.4, 1);
  -moz-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0.4, 1);
  transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0.4, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -300px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -300px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -300px, 0);
}

.box {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0.4, 1);
  -moz-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0.4, 1);
  transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0.4, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 500px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 500px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 500px, 0);
}
.box.move {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0.4, 1);
  -moz-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0.4, 1);
  transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0.4, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -300px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -300px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -300px, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="container">
<input type="button" class="toggle" value="CLICK ME" />    
    <p>
      In auctor lobortis lacus. Nullam sagittis. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Suspendisse enim turpis, dictum sed, iaculis a, condimentum nec, nisi. Nam eget dui.

Curabitur at lacus ac velit ornare lobortis. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Nulla porta dolor. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.
    </p>
    <p>
      In auctor lobortis lacus. Nullam sagittis. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Suspendisse enim turpis, dictum sed, iaculis a, condimentum nec, nisi. Nam eget dui.

Aliquam lobortis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Quisque libero metus, condimentum nec, tempor a, commodo mollis, magna. Praesent egestas neque eu enim.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

to be more clear on how to reproduce the problem i made some gifs:

**HOW IT SHOULD WORK**
[image: this is how it works when the page is not scrolled all the way down, thats exactly what i need it to do]

**REPRODUCING THE ERROR:**
*Scrolling the page down and clicking on the button, makes the div jump up leaving a blank space.*
[image]

I'm assuming this is a Chrome bug since it works good on Firefox (didn't test other browsers yet).
Can anyone enlighten me on what is wrong? How can i make this animation work good even when the page is scrolled down?

**EDIT:** using `translate` instead of `translate3d` does not change the strange behavior.

Comment: @Phlume are you using the codepen or the code written in my edited question?

Comment: I deleted my old comments as they were irrelevant.. I didn't scroll all the way to the bottom as instructed. My appologies. I *can reproduce this* in chrome on all layout versions.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the spefic reason why this is happening , but changing `transfrom3d` properties  to 2d `transform`  properties fixes the issue,
since you're not using the z value it works good for this scenario ;

EDIT:
rechecking the pen I saw that I had changed the translateY property...

I think the reason your issue is happening is that giving the container div an opposite transition than to box ends up leaving space at the bottom

[check my pen](http://codepen.io/maio/pen/XJGWzN).

Comment: hm i think theres something wrong with your pen. There are still `translate3d` properties and the `.container` div is not moving at all. Only the red `.box` div has the animation (and still has `translate3d` property)   
EDIT: i just tried with the `translate` property and it does the same strange behaviour, thanks for the suggestion.